# 2 (or more) forms in a modal with tabs

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal with some tabs, and each tab has its own form. I am looking for some way to change the footer so the submit works based on the active tab.

http://jsfiddle.net/r9b3ugs5/

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#One" data-toggle="tab">One</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Two" data-toggle="tab">Two</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="One">
                    <form id="FormOne" role="form" class="container-fluid" action="One.asp" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            FormOne
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="Two">
                    <form id="FormTwo" role="form" class="container-fluid" action="Two.asp" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            FormTwo
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should be the way to do this? adding one footer for each tab and show it when the tab is active? Some other way?

**UPDATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/r9b3ugs5/2/

Everthing is ok, besides the trigger url when I click in each button.

Comment: Do you have same buttons in all the tabs?

Comment: No. I would like to be free to add x buttons to tab one and y buttons to tab two

Comment: It would be better to have multiple footers in that case and show it accordingly

Comment: How can I do this? Can you please share some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the JFiddle. Look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/r9b3ugs5/1/

Instead of alerting the id you can decide which tab has to be saved using the retrieved id. All you need to do is to add an id and a unique class (mytabs here) to all the tabs (on the li tag).

```
$("#save-button").click(function() {
    alert($(".mytabs.active")[0].id);
});
```

EDIT: Actually you don't really need the class you could select over the parent ("#my-tab-ul li.active"). Several possibilities.

EDIT2: **Further explanation**

1. give the form ids like *tab-id*-form (*tab-id* = id of tab belonging to form)
2. replace the alert line with

   `$("#" + $(".mytabs.active")[0].id + "-form").submit();`

**Complete solution** (tested in IE and FF): http://jsfiddle.net/r9b3ugs5/5/

```
// optional: change the text on the button when the tab is switched
$("#tab1").click(function() {
    $("#save-button").html("Submit 1");        
});

$("#tab2").click(function() {
    $("#save-button").html("Submit 2");        
});

 $("#save-button").click(function() {
    var id = $(".mytabs.active")[0].id;
    if (id == "tab1") {
        // you can also do the submits here, then there is no need for a 
        // special id, e.g. $("#completely-unrelated-form-id").submit()
    } else {
        // other submit if done in here, however with this approach you
        // always have to modify the code when adding tabs.
    }
    $("#" + id + "-form").submit(); // == EDIT2, no more code manipulation needed
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am working on this, based on your suggestion. Gonna update when I finish.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. I've updated the question. Thanks for your time, again.

Comment: That is strange, you noticed that I removed one bracket? For me it seems to work. You didn't close the form correctly, some browsers have problem with that. Try again, I updated it. http://jsfiddle.net/r9b3ugs5/3/

Comment: It was intentional. Closing the form without putting the submit button inside it, do not submit it. I tried your update, and it is not submiting. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Not many as polite as you here I had to experience... anyways, which browser? I'm using FF 36 (old pc atm), now checking with IE it didn't work either. These are the annoying problems, didn't see the mistake, anyways conceptually there should be no change needed, I'm using stuff like this in productive environments sometimes.

Comment: Chrome, last version. But the main environment is IE9. The way I put in the update works. But this is the first time I have to put 2 forms in the same modal with tabs.

Comment: I've seen the mistake, you made a mix between "my" solution and the other one that was proposed. Let me show you... some moment please

Comment: Thanks, saw the changes. Gonna test it. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: OK I updated the fiddle and the solution, take care you take the right link 5/5, I saved some non-sense in between (5/4).

Answer (score 2):

use jquery:

```
    $("#tab1").click(function(){
    $("#submit1").css("display","inline-block !important");
    $("#submit2").css("display","none");
});

$("#tab2").click(function(){
    $("#submit2").css("display","inline-block !important");
    $("#submit1").css("display","none");
});
```

**Fiddle:** [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/alihesari/6j4xsss4/)

Comment: Thanks. The main problem now is how to associate the form submit link for each button, as each tab has it own link to submit.

Comment: @Khrys You can use AJAX submit form to do it

Comment: @Khrys Are you able to use Ajax?

Comment: Not this time. Thanks for the suggestion.