# Refreshing Form or DIV Container in BootStrap Tab on Input Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Boot-Strap Tab as follows

```
<html> <head>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- INPUT PANEL -->
<div class="CustomSideBar" style="width: 300px ">
  <form class="well" method="POST" id="inputForm">
     <select name="pickTheSelected" onchange="??????">
          <option value="OPTION1">OPTION1</option> 
          <option value="OPTION2">OPTION2</option> 
     </select>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- BOOT STRAP -->
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>    
</ul>

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
        <!-- IT Can be a Form or Div Container -->
        <div class="well"  id="LinePlot">
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab2">
        <!-- IT Can be a Form or Div Container -->
        <div class="well" id="BarPlot">

        </div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Consider the BootStrap Tab div Container with ID id="LinePlot" or id="BarPlot", plot's a graph based on the Input selected within the form with ID "inputForm"
I have an Idea to Plot data or Graph based on the Input selected.
I am fine with it.

But need information or help on my requirements.

**Requirement**

1) Based on the Input Change with in Form ID "inputForm"
I need the Active Bootstrap Tab DIV container to be refreshed. 
While the Unselected tab should not be refreshed

Example if active Tab is with ID "tab2" on Input change within form with ID "inputForm" I need the div container belonging to "BarPlot" to be refreshed. While div container within the "LinePlot "need not be refershed-
And vice versa if "tab1" is active.

2)
Similarly the Div container should Load only in the Tab is active or Selected. Based on the Selected value in the Form with ID "InputForm".

Hope I have explained my requirement

I am finding it very difficult for me to achieve my requirement 
Based on JavaScript. More over I am new to it.

Would it be possible if someone, let me know the way to achieve my requirement. 
Either via JavaScript / JQuery or Bootstrap with Ajax.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not that hard with jquery. You can get the data with the `$.ajax()` function. Load the data into the target with `$("#target-id").html(newContent);`. To know which tab is active you can select over the parent, in your case `$("#myTabContent div.tab-pane.active")` (in your code only one tab should have class active). To get the value of an input: `$("#my-input").val()`. You don't have to specify any event handlers in html, for this you can use `$("...").click(function() {...} )`, `.change()` and so on.

Comment: Hello Maraca, Thanks you for Response. Can you provide me any working example

Comment: No sorry, this would take too long. All those functions are well documented. Enter jquery + what you want in a search engine and you will get a hit. Same for the bootstrap tabs. If you present a complete JFiddle, with just 1 error then I could correct it maybe. But just putting html tags in there and saying oh there is just one big mistake is not how it works.

Comment: Thanks You. Let me try to figure this out.. Myself

Comment: Here is another question I answered, maybe you can use it as a start.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627031/2-or-more-forms-in-a-modal-with-tabs/29627372#29627372

Comment: Thanks Maraca, I have managed to figure how to make that work.